# AngularChosen change the single select input to be like the multiple select

Tags: angularjs, jquery-chosen, angular-chosen

I hope someone can help me with this. I'm using [angular-chosen](https://github.com/localytics/angular-chosen) and I'm really happy with it, but I want to remove the button type select box with the single select, into the text type box that's used with the multiple select, an example [here](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/).

I tried using a different module, [acute-select](http://john-oc.github.io/), because the combo mode was exactly what I wanted, but the module is still too incomplete and I can't use it.

Does anyone know how I can achieve this using the chosen directive, or is there maybe another, working, module?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up forking acute-select in order to make something that suited my needs. I removed most of the other features and only kept the combo-box.

It's tailored to be used in a bootstrap dropdown in a bootstrap nav-bar.

You can view the demo and source [here](http://nvernooy.github.io/acute-select/).